# What is the significance of System.setProperty() while working with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In selenium, why do we add `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");` within `static{}` block ?

```
public class Demo{
static{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Comment: it's not must to have condition, here static block would be executed first.

Comment: Good question - to you, why would you do that? Guess you read it somewhere, what was the explanation. What it does it's too set a system property with that name, to have that value; the benefit will be you won't need to give the path to the chromedriver upon initializing it.

Comment: You really shouldn't do this.  The whole point of that property is that different machines can set the property to point the code towards the location of the chromedriver executable on that specific machine.  You are hard coding it to overwrite any machine specific config and force it to a specific location that will be wrong everywhere but on your machine.  If you are going to do something like this you should check to see if it has already been set first and only do this if it has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

While working with Selenium-Java client, the Java platform itself uses the [*Properties*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) object to maintain its own configuration. The *System* class maintains the *Properties* object that describes the configuration of the current working environment. System properties include information about the *current user*, the *current version of the Java runtime*, the *character used to separate components of a file path name*, etc.

The following [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) describes some of the most important system properties:

[image: Java_SystemProperties]

> **Security consideration**: Access to system properties can be restricted by the [Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html). This is most often an issue in applets, which are prevented from reading some system properties, and from writing any system properties. For more on accessing system properties in applets, refer to [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/properties.html) in the [Doing More With Java Rich Internet Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/index.html) lesson.

---

### Reading System Properties

The *System* class has two methods used to read system properties: `getProperty` and `getProperties`.

The *System* class has two different versions of `getProperty`. Both retrieve the value of the property named in the argument list. The simpler of the two `getProperty` methods takes a single argument, a property key For example, to get the value of `path.separator`, use the following statement:

```
System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

The `getProperty` method returns a string containing the value of the property. If the property does not exist, this version of `getProperty` returns null.

The other version of `getProperty` requires two String arguments: the first argument is the key to look up and the second argument is a default value to return if the key cannot be found or if it has no value. For example, the following invocation of `getProperty` looks up the `System` property called `subliminal.message`. This is not a valid system property, so instead of returning null, this method returns the default value provided as a second argument: "Selenium WebDriver!"

```
System.getProperty("subliminal.message", "Selenium WebDriver!");
```

The last method provided by the *System* class to access property values is the `getProperties` method, which returns a [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object. This object contains a complete set of system property definitions.

A *Java* program to extract the *System Properties*:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package Java_Experiments;

  public class system_getProperty {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
          System.out.println(System.getProperty("subliminal.message", "Selenium WebDriver!"));
          System.out.println("Java Runtime Environment version: "+System.getProperty("java.version"));
          System.out.println("Java Runtime Environment vendor: "+System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
          System.out.println("Java vendor URL: "+System.getProperty("java.vendor.url"));
          System.out.println("Java installation directory: "+System.getProperty("java.home"));
          System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine specification version: "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version"));
          System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine specification vendor: "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.vendor"));
          System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine specification name: "+System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.name"));
          System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine implementation version: "+System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));
          System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor: "+System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor"));
          System.out.println("Java Virtual Machine implementation name: "+System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
          System.out.println("Java Runtime Environment specification version: "+System.getProperty("java.specification.version"));
          System.out.println("Java Runtime Environment specification vendor: "+System.getProperty("java.specification.vendor"));
          System.out.println("Java Runtime Environment specification name: "+System.getProperty("java.specification.name"));
          System.out.println("Java class format version number: "+System.getProperty("java.class.version"));
          System.out.println("Java class path: "+System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
          System.out.println("List of paths to search when loading libraries: "+System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
          System.out.println("Default temp file path: "+System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
          System.out.println("Name of JIT compiler to use: "+System.getProperty("java.compiler"));
          System.out.println("Path of extension directory or directories: "+System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs"));
          System.out.println("Operating system name: "+System.getProperty("os.name"));
          System.out.println("Operating system architecture: "+System.getProperty("os.arch"));
          System.out.println("Operating system version: "+System.getProperty("os.version"));
          System.out.println("File separator: "+System.getProperty("file.separator"));
          System.out.println("Path separator: "+System.getProperty("path.separator"));
          System.out.println("Line separator: "+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
          System.out.println("User's account name: "+System.getProperty("user.name"));
          System.out.println("User's home directory: "+System.getProperty("user.home"));
          System.out.println("User's current working directory: "+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe
  Selenium WebDriver!
  Java Runtime Environment version: 1.8.0_172
  Java Runtime Environment vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java vendor URL: http://java.oracle.com/
  Java installation directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172
  Java Virtual Machine specification version: 1.8
  Java Virtual Machine specification vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java Virtual Machine specification name: Java Virtual Machine Specification
  Java Virtual Machine implementation version: 25.172-b11
  Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java Virtual Machine implementation name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
  Java Runtime Environment specification version: 1.8
  Java Runtime Environment specification vendor: Oracle Corporation
  Java Runtime Environment specification name: Java Platform API Specification
  Java class format version number: 52.0
  Java class path: C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation\bin;C:\Utility\log4j-1.2.15.jar\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\Utility\Sikuli\sikulixapi.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\poi-3.15.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\poi-examples-3.15.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\poi-excelant-3.15.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\poi-ooxml-3.15.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\ooxml-lib\curvesapi-1.04.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\lib\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\lib\commons-collections4-4.1.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\lib\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Utility\poi-bin-3.15-20160924\poi-3.15\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Utility\Zip4j_1.3.2\zip4j_1.3.2.jar;C:\Utility\PhantomjsDriver1.1.0\phantomjsdriver-1.4.4.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\fontbox-2.0.9.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\ghost4j-1.0.1.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\itext-2.1.7.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jbig2-imageio-3.0.0.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jboss-vfs-3.2.12.Final.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jna-4.1.0.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\lept4j-1.9.4.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\pdfbox-2.0.9.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\pdfbox-debugger-2.0.9.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\pdfbox-tools-2.0.9.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\tess4j-4.0.2.jar;C:\Utility\tess4j_jar_files\xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar;C:\Utility\ashot-1.5.x\ashot-1.4.4.jar;C:\Utility\selenium-server-standalone\selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar;D:\SeleniumJavaUtilities\WebDriverReleases\htmlUnitDriver\htmlunit-driver-2.33.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar;D:\SeleniumJavaUtilities\Shutterbug\selenium-shutterbug-0.9.jar
  List of paths to search when loading libraries: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_172/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Python\;C:\Windows\System32;C:\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\AtechM_03\node_modules\mocha;C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\AtechM_03\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\AtechM_03\Desktop;;.
  Default temp file path: C:\Users\ATECHM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
  Name of JIT compiler to use: null
  Path of extension directory or directories: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
  Operating system name: Windows 8
  Operating system architecture: amd64
  Operating system version: 6.2
  File separator: \
  Path separator: ;
  Line separator: 

  User's account name: AtechM_03
  User's home directory: C:\Users\AtechM_03
  User's current working directory: C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\learn-automation
  ```

---

### Writing System Properties

To modify the existing set of system properties, use `System.setProperties`. This method takes a `Properties` object that has been initialized to contain the properties to be set. This method replaces the entire set of system properties with the new set represented by the `Properties` object.

> **Note**: Changing system properties is potentially dangerous and should be done with discretion. Many system properties are not reread after start-up and are there for informational purposes. Changing some properties may have unexpected side-effects.

The `setProperties` method changes the set of system properties for the current running application. These changes are not persistent. That is, changing the system properties within an application will not affect future invocations of the Java interpreter for this or any other application. The runtime system re-initializes the system properties each time its starts up. If changes to system properties are to be persistent, then the application must write the values to some file before exiting and read them in again upon startup.

Comment: unrelated to the topic, but your PDFBox version is outdated. 2.0.13 is current.