# How to define the proxy settings in the new Algolia API v3 without System properties

Tags: java, proxy, algolia

I use Algolia 3.9.0 client under Java 8.

As advised in the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/getting-started/quick-start/tutorials/quick-start-with-the-api-client/java/?language=java#proxy) you need to set up proxy settings using the system properties. I prefer not to use this mechanism because properties can interfere with other components' properties as they can set the same properties too ([Read more about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502234/what-is-the-significance-of-system-setproperty-while-working-with-selenium)). Is there any way to set the values like in v2 client ?

```
 client.setProxy(new HttpHost(conf.getProxyHost(), conf.getProxyPort()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work as you want you should a custom `HttpRequester`, later make an instance of it with a new `HttpClient` using `HttpClientConfiguration` having your proxy config, here's a working code:

MyCustomRequester class:

```
public class MyCustomRequester implements HttpRequester {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    public MyCustomRequester(HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<HttpResponse> performRequestAsync(HttpRequest request) {
        return ... httpClient.execute(...) ...;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
   ...
    }

}
```

main method for testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SearchConfig config = new SearchConfig
            .Builder("undefined", "undefined").build();

    HttpClientConfiguration httpClientConfiguration = new HttpClientConfiguration();
    httpClientConfiguration.setProxyHost("host");
    httpClientConfiguration.setProxyPort(2020);

    HttpClient httpClient = // create a new httpClient with custom httpClientConfiguration;
    ...
    SearchClient client = new SearchClient(config, myCustomRequester);
}
```

> If you want to inject your own HttpClient you can inject it by constructor into all the clients classes of library. The latter has to implement the HttpRequester interface. In that case you don’t need algoliasearch-apache anymore as a dependency.

For more details see this [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/getting-started/quick-start/tutorials/quick-start-with-the-api-client/java/?language=java)

Comment: Thanks but your solution implies the creation of a new requester. I am not sure if I have time to write a new one as it needs to be sync and async in the same time. I'll consider your solution the next week as I am still exploring a new solution.